# On smaller displays show one part of the sidebar above and a second part below the main content

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a two-column bootstrap layout: a main content column and a sidebar column on the right.

- On big enough screens, both sidebar DIVs (**abovemain** and **belowmain**) are to be shown to the right of the main content.
- On smaller screens, I want one part of the sidebar (**abovemain**) to be displayed above the main content, the rest of it (**belowmain**) below the main content.

Expected result on a big enough screen:

```
Column 1       | Column 2
-------------- | ---------------------------------------
Main Main Main | Above Main Content or Side (X)
Main Main Main | ---------------------------------------
Main Main Main | Below Main Content or Side
```

Expected Result on a small screen:

```
Above Main Content or Side (X)
---------------------------------
Main Main Main
Main Main Main
Main Main Main
Main Main Main
---------------------------------
Below Main Content or Side
```

```php
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 narrow">Above Main Content or Side (X)</div>
   <div class="col-md-8">Main Content</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="abovemain">Above Main Content or Side (X)</div>
       <div class="belowmain">Below Main Content or Side</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My terrible solution so far: **repeating** the output (X), one time into the "**narrow**"-DIV, a second time into the "**abovemain**"-DIV, then hide one or the other by css according to the media-width:

```css
   .narrow { display:none; }
   .abovemain { display:block; }
   @media (max-width: 800px) {
      .narrow { display:block; }
      .abovemain { display:none; }
   }
```

Do you know a no-script-solution where the output doesn't have to be repeated?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `css grid` to achieve your desired layout

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "main main main sidetop"
                       "main main main sidetop"
                       "main main main sidebottom";
}

.main {
  background: red;
  grid-area: main;
}

.sidebar-top {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: sidetop;
  height: 100px;
}

.sidebar-bottom {
  background: green;
  grid-area: sidebottom;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .grid {
     grid-template-areas: "sidetop     sidetop   sidetop"
                          "  main        main      main"
                          "sidebottom sidebottom sidebottom";
  }
  
  .main {
     height: 200px;
  }
  
  .sidebar-top, .sidebar-bottom {
     height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="main">Main</div>
  <div class="sidebar-top">sidebar top</div>
  <div class="sidebar-bottom">sidebar bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the responsive display classes (d-md-block) and floats to pull the content to the right side on `md` and larger...

```
<div class="row d-md-block">
    <div class="col-md-8 float-left">Main Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 float-right order-first">Above Main Content or Side (X)</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 float-right">Below Main Content or Side</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/guHhCc51o6