# Reorder columns in mobile for Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and got into a unique situation where I have to re-order from the following format in desktop version:

```
[        ] [column 2]
[column-1] [column 3]
[        ]
```

to mobile version:

```
[column 2]
[column 1]
[column 3]
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            [column 1]
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    [column 2]
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 order-last">
                    [column 3]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to reposition the columns they must be in the same parent `.row`. Use the Bootstrap float classes and `d-sm-block` to disable the flexbox on larger screens. Then `order-first` will position the divs as desired on mobile...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-sm-block align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-7 float-left">
            [column 1]
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 float-left order-first">
            [column 2]
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 float-right">
            [column 3]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/8bmIH3XGnL

---

Related:

[On smaller displays show one part of the sidebar above and a second part below the main content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528170/)
[One tall div next to two shorter divs on Desktop and stacked on Mobile with Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141694/)
[Bootstrap with different order on mobile version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882342/bootstrap-with-different-order-on-mobile-version)